# SQL Server Agent log is showing error [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (connexecutecacheableOP)

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Can You please suggest me why it Happens and how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Was your SQL Server stopped or failed over at that time? That would explain the messages.

The errorlog file (created by the database engine) might tell you why. Or the Windows event log.